# How to plot a lot of LineString at once efficiently in Mapbox

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geocoding, mapbox

I have a LineString geoJSON dataset (about 50000 line strings) which I need to plot in mapbox using leaflet. Currently it takes a lot of time to render the map. Since I need to update the map every 30 seconds with new data, if it is taking 3 minutes to render the whole map then there will be no point to visualizing the data.

So my code for displaying the 50000 LineStrings is below:

```
        var map = L.map('map').setView([36.447488,102.463303], 12);
        L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=token', {
            maxZoom: 18,
            attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
                '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
                'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
            id: 'mapbox.streets'
        }).addTo(map);
var options = {
            position: 'topleft',
            title: 'Search',
            placeholder: 'enter  id ',
            maxResultLength: 15,
            threshold: 0.5,
            showInvisibleFeatures: true,
            showResultFct: function(feature,container) {
                props = feature.properties;
                var name = L.DomUtil.create('b', null, container);
                name.innerHTML = props.id;

                container.appendChild(L.DomUtil.create('br', null, container));

                var cat = props.id
                    info = '' + cat + ', ' + 'th id';
                container.appendChild(document.createTextNode(info));
            }
        };

    var searchCtrl = L.control.fuseSearch(options);

    searchCtrl.addTo(map);


    var geojson;

    function getColor(d) {


           if(d==10 || d==9 || d==8){
               return '#ff0000';
           }

           else {

               return '#00ff65';

           }

    } 


    function style(feature) {

        return {
            weight: 2,
            opacity: 1,

            color: getColor(feature.properties.points),

            fillOpacity: 0.7,

        };
    }


    function highlightFeature(e) {
    var layer = e.target;

    layer.setStyle({
        weight: 2,
        color:'#007d80',
        dashArray: '',
        fillOpacity: 0.7
    });


    if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera && !L.Browser.edge) {
        layer.bringToFront();
    }

    info.update(layer.feature.properties);

    }
function resetHighlight(e) {
    geojson.resetStyle(e.target);
    info.update();
}
function zoomToFeature(e) {
    map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
    map.doubleClickZoom.disable();
}
var info = L.control();


info.update = function (props) {
    this._div.innerHTML = '<h4><b>Link: <b></h4>' +  (props ?
        '<b>LineString ' + props.id + '</b><br />'  
        : 'Hover over a LineSting');


};


function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
     feature.layer = layer;

    layer.on({
        mouseover: highlightFeature,
        mouseout: resetHighlight,


    });
    var popupContent = 
      '<b>Link ' + feature.properties.id + '</b>';

    layer.bindPopup(popupContent);          
    feature.layer = layer;

}




function mapupdatecolor(){




          $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            async : false,
            url: 'http:dataurl', 
            success: function(data) {

                console.log("sucess"); 

                for (i = 0; i<40000; i++) { 



                          links['features'][i]['properties']['points']=data[i].points;





                }


                if (geojson) {

                    geojson.remove(); 
                    console.log("removed");

                }




                function picnicFilter(feature) {
                      if (feature.properties.points >= 9) return true
                    }




                geojson = L.geoJson(lines, {
                    filter: picnicFilter,
                    style: style,
                    onEachFeature: onEachFeature

                     }).addTo(map);



                console.log("update done");

            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

                alert(thrownError);
              },
            complete: function() {

             setTimeout(mapupdatecolor, 5000);
            }
          });


        // schedule the first invocation:








}

geojson = L.geoJson(lines, {
    style: style,
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(map);


info.onAdd = function (map) {
    this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info'); // create a div with a class "info"
    this.update();
    return this._div;
};




searchCtrl.indexFeatures(links.features, ['id']);
info.addTo(map);

setTimeout( mapupdatecolor, 5000);
```

My geoJSON data is like below:

```
var lines=    
    {

"type":"FeatureCollection",

"features": [                                             
    {"type": "Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString", "coordinates":[[102.463303,36.447488],[102.514114,36.439755],..]},"properties": {"id":"01","points":9}},
    {"type": "Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString", "coordinates":[[102.593765,36.414341],[102.634964,36.402183],..]},"properties": {"id":"02","points":8}},
    {"type": "Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString", "coordinates":[[102.880783,36.485038],[102.882156,36.561187],..]},"properties":{"id":"03","points":10}}
```

........
and upto id 50000
                ]};

By the way My each LineStrings have more than two coordinates (nearly 20-30 coordinates)

What is the way to make the data render fast in my case?

Comment: Would a raster solution be an option or do you need full access to the complete linestrings at any zoomlevel?

Comment: I actually need full access to the complete linestrings at any zoomlevel